# What tool can I use to manage my budget, transactions and bills?

Tags: finance

I would like a software that allow me to record my expenses and incomes for different accounts. There must be categories of expenses and incomes, as well a sub(-sub(-sub(...)))categories.

I would like to define monthly budgets. It would be appreciated that a budget can concern two accounts (for example : I'll spend 200$ in october for buying groceries, but the money can come either from my current account and from my cash).

A plus would be that I can link my bills (pdf) to the matching transactions.

For now I'm using a self-made excel file, that was pretty hard to set up. I'm satisfied of what I done, but it's clearly not enough for me and I'm looking for more.

The software can be web-based or a windows heavy client (can also be an app for Windows 8/10). But it must also be mobile friendly (either an (Android) app or a mobile-adapted website).

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Software recommendations are probably out of scope here, but the general class you're looking for is known as "personal finance"  programs.

Comment: On what operating system? Or do you want something online?

Comment: Hello Gilles. Thank you for your answer. I've just edited my post in order to answer your questions.

Comment: If you're looking for an Android app, please check with [my corresponding lists](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/finance). For budgeting only, [Financisto](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.orangesoftware.financisto) might be a great solution: feature-rich and open source. If you need the app to access your bank accounts, that's another thing: here I cannot say a word as those apps are often country- or even bank specific.

Comment: I do not need to connect with my bank accounts. It's sure it would be extra, but I don't think this is possible at the moment in my country (Belgium). I'll check Financisto but it seems a bit old and a better-looking app would be nice (though if that app offers better features I'll use it).

Comment: How important is having many levels of subcategorization? [YNAB](https://www.youneedabudget.com/) fits most of your criteria except that it only supports 2 levels of categories

Comment: This one seems very interesting. I'll give it a try. 34 days should be enough to have an idea of the capabilities of the software. Thanks a lot!